# PHP connect using JDBC

Tags: java, php, jdbc, bbj

I have DBMS called BBJ DBMS. And installed JDBC , connecting to it via Java with no problems. but the thing i need to connect to it using PHP code. and this DBMC has ODBC only for windows. so i have no choice other than JDBC.

What is the most efficient solution for this case ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

JDBC is just for Java (hence the name, Java Database Connectivity)...

Check out [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for connecting to a database with PHP.

Comment: Or ODBC is available too... But I haven't worked with it so I can't tell you much about it.

Comment: hey thanks for response. BBJ is offering ODBC driver for windows OS only. and i cant use it. so i have no choice other using JDBC. with it.

Comment: No, it is just JDBC or ODBC (for windows). because it is not very used DBMS.

Comment: u might think of make it independent of the client which's connecting to it, either a java /php or maybe .net in the future..
i've heard about PJBS JDBC-PHP bridge ...google it , it might help

Comment: @Br3x could u elaborate more on that ?

Answer (score 2):

BBj supports REST which can be consumed from most languages, including PHP. You would basically publish your data file as REST web service and then consume it using the REST API. There is a plug-in that supports publishing REST web services with CRUD functionality with BBj:

https://github.com/BBj-Plugins/RestBridge